# ng-model not working with select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, html-select

This might probably be a duplicate question but I am stuck while showing the default value from my data while binding another array to dropdown list. The list gets populated but the selected value which should show up after loading is not showing up.

### This is my sample code:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="myCntrl">
  <select class="form-control right" 
  ng-if="subscription.subscribedAddresses.ChannelType=='EMAIL'" 
  ng-model="subscription.subscribedAddresses.ChannelAddress" 
  ng-options="channel.ChannelAddress for channel in commInfo.emails track by channel.ChannelAddress" required>
  </select>
</div>
```

JS:

---

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('myCntrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.commInfo = {
  "emails": [{
    "ChannelAddressId": 5000054652,
    "DeliveryChannel": "EMAIL",
    "ChannelType": null,
    "ChannelAddress": "ya_ajay@net.com"
  }, {
    "ChannelAddressId": 5000075277,
    "DeliveryChannel": "EMAIL",
    "ChannelType": null,
    "ChannelAddress": "yad_ay@ts.com"
  }, {
    "ChannelAddressId": 5000075278,
    "DeliveryChannel": "EMAIL",
    "ChannelType": null,
    "ChannelAddress": "yadav_aaj@gmail.com"
  }, {
    "ChannelAddressId": 5000075279,
    "DeliveryChannel": "EMAIL",
    "ChannelType": "UNKNOWN",
    "ChannelAddress": "test_ay@mail.com"
  }],
  "phones": [{
    "ChannelAddressId": 5000075390,
    "DeliveryChannel": "PHON",
    "ChannelType": "UNKNOWN",
    "ChannelAddress": "4561237895"
  }, {
    "ChannelAddressId": 5000075397,
    "DeliveryChannel": "PHON",
    "ChannelType": "UNKNOWN",
    "ChannelAddress": "7894561236"
  }]
};
$scope.subscription = {"serviceName":"RAM Month","subscribedAddresses":{"ChannelAddress":"yad_ajay@ts.com","ChannelType":"EMAIL"}};
}]);
```

Here is the Plunkr:
[Plunkr: Dropdown issue - Angularjs](https://plnkr.co/edit/XiOkbgJnZ5YteDRgTV06?p=preview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code seems fine to me, however you init the subscription.subscribeAddresses.ChannelAddress to "yad_ajay@ts.com". I don't see any **yad_ajay@ts.com** in your commInfo. Guess that's the proble.

EDIT : here is  a working select of your plunker

```
 <select class="form-control right" 
  ng-if="subscription.subscribedAddresses.DeliveryChannel=='EMAIL'" 
  ng-model="subscription.subscribedAddresses" 
  ng-options="channel as channel.ChannelAddress for channel in commInfo.emails track by channel.ChannelAddressId" 
  required>
  </select>
```

Changes : Change ChannelType to DeliveryCHannel in the ng-if

Changes ng-options add track by to help angular identify unicity of objects

Working Plunker :- 
http://plnkr.co/edit/LSbJ2RVRw9zJleSwP3YT?p=preview

Comment: no that is not working, see the [difference here](https://plnkr.co/edit/yGKSGS70yZ4QGY3Qsp2T?p=preview)

Comment: i made it works, see my answer with the edit link : https://plnkr.co/edit/LSbJ2RVRw9zJleSwP3YT?p=preview

Comment: It's even more simpler than this: Simply change this your ng-model: `ng-model="subscription.subscribedAddresses"`

Comment: @Walfrat could you explain why it wasn't working with `track by channel.ChannelAddress`?

Comment: channel is an object, angular don't know how do make match objects between them in order to set the current selected value in the select. This is why you have to specify track by. This mean too thatAddressId must be unique or the widget will fail with an error in your console

Comment: Thanks Walfrat for the insight! Working just fine as intended. Though I didn't have to change the ChannelType to DeliveryChannel in ng-if and I can't change it also because I want the control to be added in HTML only if the ChannelType in subscription object is EMAIL.

Comment: Well i add to change something in the ng-if at start because the select wasn't showing but this wasn't relevant to the problem aniway

Answer (score 0):

the ng-model does not fit to any of the models in the commInfo list.
Here your solution.

```
[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6b3ntn73/28/)
```